# SVN help:: svn: invalid option: --trust-server-cert

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ubuntu-9.04

I want to bypass certificate checking. I tried using `svn --trust-server-cert update`, but I get an error, `svn: invalid option: --trust-server-cert`.

I am on ubuntu and the svn version  is 1.5.4.  Is there any other way to bypass the certificate? Ubuntu won't automatically update my svn to 1.6.xx, which I think has this option.  (In any case, I have heard that 1.6.xx has compatibility problems with some apache modules so is not fully safe to install?).

Anyone with a suggestion?

Thanks

JP

Comment: Are you using an https connection? And is there anything requiring the use of https connections?

Answer (score -2):

what version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you had a look at the latest binaries built by WANdisco? http://wandisco.com/subversion/os/downloads

I would say that Subversion 1.6 IS safe to use, as many large organisations have been using it for some time (I work for WANdisco, and am talking from first hand experience based on what our customers are using).

The feature you want is definately in Subversion 1.6

Regards,
Jon

Comment: Sorry but this just an advertisement: if you want to get subversion, get it at the official site http://subversion.apache.org/